# Ionic resolve a promise on app start

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am running the ionic framework v1 and my app does some initial set up before getting started.  Part of this set up requires getting the users location which should be completed before the app calls any other initialization function.  Otherwise, it won't work.

So my question is how do I get ionic to call a function - Wait for the promise to resolve.  And then begin to initialize the controller, routes, and whatnot.

It looks like the `$ionicPlatform.ready` function is called before app load but if I put it in there it does not block and it just proceeds to begin to initialize my app before the promise is returned.